# Add additional attributes to JSON response in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, servlets

I have a service which is returning a List in JSON format.
Please find below code :

```
public List<SampleList> getValues() {
        List<SampleList> sample = null;
        sample= DAOFactory.sampleDAO.findByCriteria().add(Restrictions.isNull("endDate")).list();
        return sample;
    }

Class SampleList.java
public class SampleList {
    private Integer categoryId;
    private String  categoryName;
//getter setter 
}
```

Now my service is returning the JSON like below

```
{
categoryId : 1,
categoryName : "Test"
}
```

But I need anotherlist to be encapsulated here. Iw ant below output

```
{
categoryId : 1,
categoryName : "Test"
subCategory:
 {
  name: ""
 } 
}
```

For `subCategory` attribute I have another class similar to SampleList.java. I can get the sub categories corresponding to each category. Can anyone help me out to get expected response?

**I dont want to touch my SampleList class.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend your class SampleList

```
Class SampleList.java
public class SampleList {
    private Integer categoryId;
    private String  categoryName;
    private SubCategory subCategory;
//getter setter
```

And before you return your list of course you have to set the correct subCategory in your SampleList item.

If you don't want to spoil your SampleList class of course you could add a layer of DTO objects and map between them or manipulate the response directly e.g. with [ResponseBodyAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html)

Comment: Yes I dont want to spoil my SampleList class.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach : 1**

```
public class SampleList
{
    private Integer categoryId;
    private String categoryName;

    // Getter and Setter
}

public class SampleList2
{
   private String name;
   // Getter and Setter
}
```

// Logic to get the JSON value without mapping two different classes

```
private void getJsonValue() throws JsonProcessingException, JSONException
{
    SampleList sampleList = new SampleList();
    sampleList.setCategoryId(1);
    sampleList.setCategoryName("cat 1");
    
    String sampleListJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(sampleList);
    
    SampleList2 sampleList2 = new SampleList2();
    sampleList2.setName("Sub category");
    
    String valueOfSample2 = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(sampleList2);
    
    JSONObject sampleListJsonObj = new JSONObject(sampleListJson); // for class SampleList
    JSONObject sampleList2JsonObj = new JSONObject(valueOfSample2); // for class SampleList2
    
    sampleListJsonObj.put("subCategory", sampleList2JsonObj);
    
    System.out.println(sampleListJsonObj.toString());
}
```

**Approach : 2**

```
 public class SampleList
{
    private Integer categoryId;
    private String categoryName;
    private SampleList2 subCategory;

    // Getter and Setter
}

public class SampleList2
{
   private String name;
   // Getter and Setter
}
```

// Logic to get with mapping two classes as mentioned above

```
private static void getJsonValue() throws JsonProcessingException
{
    SampleList sampleList = new SampleList();
    sampleList.setCategoryId(1);
    sampleList.setCategoryName("cat 1");
    
    SampleList2 sampleList2 = new SampleList2();
    sampleList2.setName("Sub category");
    
    sampleList.setSubCategory(sampleList2);
    
    String jsonString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(sampleList);
    
    System.out.println(jsonString.toString());
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions on the same.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Harsh, thanks for such detailed answer. In approach 1 :     JSONObject sampleListJsonObj = new JSONObject(sampleListJson);  JSONObject only takes Map as a parameter not the String, what can be done then here?

Comment: I have used org.json.JSONObject and in its constructor, we can pass string.
Please go through https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks @harsh_jani its working with both the approaches.

Comment: Thank you. Can you vote up for this answer if it is helpful to you. :)